# Sharing Buttons not Working - Sharing Settings

Tags: options, plugin-jetpack, sharing

I'm trying to add a "share this" button to my site. I am having an issue configure this because when I go to settings -> sharing I get the image below[image]

Update: Here is my inspector error console:[image]

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /?ver=2:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /?ver=3:1
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active s0.wp.com/:9823
```

Comment: Says you need to drag services from the list into the other area. Is this right? Is something not being loaded? Does not look correct to me. Right click in Chrome and inspect element somewhere. Look for any .js errors

Comment: Please see my updated image @GhostToast

Comment: I'm sorry I can't read that. Can you paste the error as text for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you experience such issues, examine the source code of the page, and search for the stylesheet used by Jetpack on the page:

```
http://yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/sharedaddy/admin-sharing.css
```

You want to make sure that this URL can be accessed; if you use a caching service or plugin or if you have added redirection rules that impact this page, you will experience issues.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your jetpack. Try disabling other plugins, or uninstalling and reinstalling jetpack. Or seeing if you can update it. The javascript is not loading correctly for you on the admin area for some reason.

I would also view source and see where those `?ver=2:1` strings are. Those seem odd with the `/` in front of them. Usually `ver` goes directly after a javascript file.

Comment: I tried disabling all plugins and reinstalling jetpack already. It seems that it goes to `http://protechig.com?ver=2:1` I have no idea what that means

Comment: Hmm. I'm stumped. I have never seen `JQMIGRATE` before. Your other jetpack assets are still working though? You have jetpack authenticated?

Comment: I don't know that much JavaScript, knowing it i'm sure would help me in this situation. Yes, everything else works flawlessly. Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Might be related to this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/jquery-warning although notice is not the same.